# YQL equivalent of MySQL's 'INTERVAL'?

Tags: mysql, yahoo, google-docs, yql

I have a job postings board that I'm running in PHP/MySQL and thinking of trying to run it in YQL and Google Docs instead. I have a line of MySQL that fetches job postings that have been posted in the last 60 days only:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `job` WHERE Curdate( ) <= DATE_ADD( `postdate` , INTERVAL 60 DAY ) ORDER BY `postdate` DESC;";
```

Is there a YQL equivalent of this? (The format of the timestamp column in the spreadsheet of form submissions in Google Docs is:

```
2/11/2011 10:23:37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YQL doesn't currently have the option of custom functions within queries, so your `Curdate()`, `DATE_ADD()`, etc. are out of the question.  However, there is no reason why you could not craft queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM job WHERE postdate > $date ORDER BY postdate DESC;
```

Where `$date` is an integer timestamp (if that is available in your Google doc?). Or,

```
SELECT * FROM job WHERE interval = 60;
```

This latter query would need a bespoke [Data Table](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-chapter.html) to interpret the query parameter(s) and format a query against your Google doc.  An advantage of crafting your own table would be that you are able to use JavaScript (in an `<execute>` block) to perform server-side processing (like one would in PHP) in YQL.